# => Lambda expression in global variable

Tags: c#, lambda, c#-6.0

It looks like he is trying to set the global "value" to a field in the constructor.

Is this even possible?

```
public class TestLambda
{
    private bool value => inputValue == null;

    public TestLambda(string inputValue)
    {
        // do stuff

    }
}
```

Comment: The `inputValue` used in the initializer for `value` isn't the same one as is used in the TestLambda constructor.

Comment: As-is, the code won't compile because `inputValue` doesn't exist in the scope of `value`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is valid C# 6 syntax for a Expression-bodied function member, given that `inputValue` is a field in your class.

```
public class TestLambda
{
    private string inputValue; // necessary

    private bool value => inputValue == null;

    public TestLambda(string inputValue)
    {
        this.inputValue = inputValue;

    }
}
```

It can be found on the [Roslyns 'New Language Features in C# 6'](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/New-Language-Features-in-C%23-6).

Comment: For completeness you could post the full property that this is shorthand syntax for.

Comment: That basically was the code. I can't post the actual code for security purposes, but this was on a GUI Form change that he was making just before he left two weeks ago. He was a c# "expert" and was always "updating" our code to the point were it's not stable and we are having to rewrite entire sections of it. The #6 is probably the answer. He probably upgraded to the development environment without telling anyone.

Answer (score 1):

It's a C# 6 syntax for a expression-bodied property. It's a get-only property, returning `inputValue == null`.

C# 5 and below equivalent is

```
private bool value
{
    get { return inputValue == null; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is legal C# 6.0 syntax, provided that `TestLambda` has a field called `inputValue`.

The equivalent code written without the expression-bodied member would look like this:

```
public class TestLambda
{
    private string inputValue;

    private bool value
    {
        get { return inputValue == null; }
    }

    public TestLambda(string inputValue)
    {
        this.inputValue = inputValue;
    }
}
```